# Posts are not sorting based on the meta key values

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

Custom meta query is not sorting the posts correctly by meta keys. If I have subscription type then those posts should come first after that the posts for  those meta key is not exist.

I am trying the below code but it is not working correctly.

```
function apply_projects_query_filter ($query)
{

    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' && $query->is_main_query()) {

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key'=>'subscription_type',
               'value'=>'subscription_type_yearly',
               'compare'=>'==',
            ),
            array(
               'key'=>'subscription_type',
               'value'=>'subscription_type_monthly',
               'compare'=>'==',
            ),
            array(
               'key'=>'subscription_type',
               'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        //$query->set('meta_key', 'subscription_type'); 
        //if($query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'subscription_type')
        //{
        $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC'));
        //}else{
           //$query->set('orderby', 'date');
       // }
        //if($query)
        //$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value title');

        //$query->set('order', 'DESC');
        return $query;
    }


    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort on 'meta_value' a meta_key must be provided outside of the meta_query (the old way). OR, when using meta_query:

Add an **array key** (string) of choice to the meta_query clause(s), on which value you want to order by.

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'sort_yearly' => array(
        'key'=>'subscription_type',
        'value'=>'subscription_type_yearly',
        'compare'=>'==',
    ),
) );
$query->set('orderby', array('sort_yearly' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC'));
```